# C# Нужно отправить Get запрос на якорную ссылку

Tags: c#, xnet

В общем есть ссылка вида site.com/#loginpass?parametr=value
Перехожу с браузера все норм.
Пытаюсь отправить с xnet, get запрос идет только на http://site.com/.
Как отправить запрос?

```
var req = new HttpRequest();
string loli = req.Get("help.site.com/#HelpWithLoginInfoSelectAccount/?s=" 
      + pars1[1] + "&code=" + pars2[1]).ToString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Якорь - точнее, Uri Fragment - это чисто клиентская вещь. Она существует только в браузере. Она не уходит на сервер, а даже если бы и уходила - нет никаких общепринятых способов на стороне сервера ее принять и обработать.

Смена этой части Url в бразуере не приводит к перезагрузке страницы. Этим обычно пользуются скрипты в одностраничных приложениях. Скорее всего где-то на странице есть скрипт, который отслеживает смену url, вырезает из него `#` и делает реальный запрос на сервер по ulr вида `site.com/loginpass?parametr=value`.

Возьмите отладчик http (fiddler2), или просто откройте dev tools в бразуере и посмотрите реально отправляемые запросы.